# Anonymous friendly CMS

Tags: content-management-system, registration, anonymous

Does anyone know of a CMS that allows user registration without requiring an email?

I know Reddit allows users to register without requiring an email but their system is overkill for what I want to do.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this:
[Joomla - How To Disable Registration Email [solved] - Zymic Webmaster Forums](http://www.zymic.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=15372)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will give this a go and cross my fingers, if it works I will let you know for future reference. Thanks for the help.